# How can I protect this exterior outlet from water and prevent smoke leakage to the interior?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, waterproofing

I have an exterior outlet in a carport that I want to protect from water and smoke.

[image]

Water: Rain cannot reach this outlet. I am only concerned about accidental water sprays from either the hose nozzle or from a bad tap/hose connection spraying water backwards.

[This is my first idea](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/leviton-extra-duty-while-in-use-cover-for-gfci-decora/1000780391):

[image]

Smoke: This is in a carport so exhaust fumes are present. People also smoke in this area. Behind this wall is the basement and sometimes a strong smoke smell is present. I'm guessing the gaps around the outlet are contributing to this.

What would you recommend to address these two issues?

Comment: The fact of the matter is that if there's a negative pressure differential inside (as there is in most homes due to bath fans and other exhaust mechanisms), sealing this one small point of entry won't help with the smoke. Maybe try inward-directed window fans (on the other side of the house) at crucial times.

Comment: How far apart do you recommend the fans be? And would a fan in the smoking area  help?

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the harder one here

## Smoke

It looks like there's a gap in the stone to the left of the outlet. I would at least try to fill it with something (maybe caulk if you want the simplest route). Once that is done, examine the box under the cover. Make sure you don't see any other intrusion points for air. The good news is any exterior rated cover should have closed-cell foam to seal the cover itself to the outlet and box.

## Water

The outlet is within 3 feet of a water source, so you're required to have a wet location cover here. The in-use cover you linked would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remove outlet, seal all air gaps.Install in-use  cover seal ,again.  Maybe have fan outside to blow smoke away.

Answer (score 2):

Also to make sure to seal any other air infiltration points, such as what looks to be an opening where your water spigot comes out of the wall.  Sealing air infiltration points should be done whether you have water there or not, to prevent carbon monoxide or other fumes from getting into your house from the carport.